# How do I add random `NA`s into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I created a data frame with random values

```
n <- 50
df <- data.frame(id = seq (1:n),
age = sample(c(20:90), n, rep = TRUE), 
sex = sample(c("m", "f"), n, rep = TRUE, prob = c(0.55, 0.45))
)
```

and would like to introduce a few `NA` values to simulate real world data. I am trying to use `apply` but cannot get there.  The line

```
apply(subset(df,select=-id), 2, function(x) {x[sample(c(1:n),floor(n/10))]})
```

will retrieve random values alright, but

```
apply(subset(df,select=-id), 2, function(x) {x[sample(c(1:n),floor(n/10))]<-NA})
```

will not set them to `NA`. Have tried `with` and `within`, too.

Brute force works:

```
for (i in (1:floor(n/10))) {
  df[sample(c(1:n), 1), sample(c(2:ncol(df)), 1)] <- NA
  }
```

But I'd prefer to use the `apply` family.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return `x` within your function:

```
> df <- apply (df, 2, function(x) {x[sample( c(1:n), floor(n/10))] <- NA; x} )
> tail(df)
      id   age  sex
[45,] "45" "41" NA 
[46,] "46" NA   "f"
[47,] "47" "38" "f"
[48,] "48" "32" "f"
[49,] "49" "53" NA 
[50,] "50" "74" "f"
```

Comment: This will also add `NA` to the id column, which is not desirable.

Comment: Then just replace `df` by `df[,c("age", "sex")]`

Comment: If you work with a data frame with greater dimension you could find it easier to replace `df` by `df[, -1]` rather than list all the columns you want to keep. The final command should be `df[, -1] <- apply (df[, -1], 2, function(x) {x[sample( c(1:n), floor(n/10))] <- NA; x} )`

Comment: @Gianluca: my answer does this (but doesn't assume that the ID column is first)

Comment: @Ben: interesting solution Ben! I prefer mine but that's mainly because I try always to store IDs as the first column. Anyway, thanks for share it with me. I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 4):

Apply returns an array, thereby converting all columns to the same type. You could use this instead:

```
df[,-1] <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
                   lapply(df[,-1], function(x) {
                     x[sample(c(1:n),floor(n/10))]<-NA
                     x
                   })
                   )
```

Or use a `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(df[,-1])+1) {
  is.na(df[sample(seq_len(n), floor(n/10)),i]) <- TRUE
}
```

Comment: You don't need `do.call(cbind.data.frame, ...)`. You can do: `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) { x[sample(c(1:n), floor(n/10))] <- NA ; x })`

Answer (score 3):

Using [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org)<sup>1</sup> you could arrive at the desired solution using the following, compact, syntax:

```
set.seed(123)
library("tidyverse")
n <- 50
df <- data.frame(
  id = seq (1:n),
  age = sample(c(20:90), n, replace  = TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("m", "f"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.55, 0.45))
)
mutate(.data = as_tibble(df),
       across(
         .cols = all_of(c("age", "sex")),
         .fns = ~ ifelse(row_number(.x) %in% sample(1:n(), size = (10 * n(
         ) / 100)), NA, .x)
       ))
```

#### Results

Approximatly 10% of values is replaced with NA per column. This follows from `sample(1:n(), size = (10 * n() / 100))`

```
count(.Last.value, sex)
#   A tibble: 3 x 2
#   sex       n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 f        21
# 2 m        24
# 3 NA        5

#  A tibble: 50 x 3
#      id   age sex  
#   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     1    50 m    
# 2     2    70 m
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> I'm loading [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org) as [`replace_na`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html) is available via [`tidyr`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html).*

Comment: I think it can be simplifed even further by using `.fns= ~ifelse(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.1), NA, .x))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to return the `x` value from the function:

```
apply(subset(df,select=-id), 2, function(x) 
     {x[sample(c(1:n),floor(n/10))]<-NA; x})
```

but you also need to assign this back to the relevant subset of the data frame (and `subset(...) <- ...` doesn't work)

```
idCol <- names(df)=="id"
df[,!idCol] <- apply(df[,!idCol], 2, function(x) 
     {x[sample(1:n,floor(n/10))] <- NA; x})
```

(if you have only a single non-ID column you'll need `df[,!idCol,drop=FALSE]`)

Comment: I noticed that with this approach, the ``sex`` variable was converted to ``chr``, while with Roland's approaches it remains a ``Factor`` (despite the presence of NAs).

Answer (score 2):

here is another simple way to go at it

your data frame

```
df<-mtcars
```

Number of missing required

```
nbr_missing<-20
```

sample row and column indices

```
y<-data.frame(row=sample(nrow(df),size=nbr_missing,replace = T),
          col=sample(ncol(df),size = nbr_missing,replace = T))
```

remove duplication

```
y<-y[!duplicated(y),]
```

use matrix indexing

```
df[as.matrix(y)]<-NA
```

Answer (score 2):

To introduce certain percentage of NAs in your dataframe you could use this:

```
while(sum(is.na(df) == TRUE) < (nrow(df) * ncol(df) * percentage/100)){
  df[sample(nrow(df),1), sample(ncol(df),1)] <- NA
}
```

you could also change "(nrow(df) * ncol(df) * percentage/100)" to a fixed number of NAs

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `prodNA` from the missForest package.

```
library(missForest)
library(dplyr)

> bind_cols(df[1],missForest::prodNA(df[-1],noNA=0.1))

# A tibble: 50 x 3
      id   age sex  
   <int> <int> <fct>
 1     1    NA m    
 2     2    84 NA   
 3     3    82 f    
 4     4    42 f    
 5     5    35 m    
 6     6    80 m    
 7     7    90 f    
 8     8    NA NA   
 9     9    89 f    
10    10    42 m    
# … with 40 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your dataframe into the following function. The only arguments are the *frame* you want to add NAs to and the number of *features* (columns) you want to have with NAs.

```
add_random_nas_to_frame <- function(frame, num_features) {
   col_order <- names(frame) 
   rand_cols <- sample(ncol(frame), num_features)
   left_overs <- which(!names(frame) %in% names(frame[,rand_cols]))
   other_frame <- frame[,left_overs]
   nas_added <- data.frame(lapply(frame[,rand_cols], function(x) x[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(sample(100, 1)/100, 0.15), size = length(x), replace = TRUE)]))
   final_frame <- cbind(other_frame, nas_added)
   final_frame <- final_frame[,col_order]
   return(final_frame)
}
```

For example, using the full dataset from banking dataset from UCI:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing

bank <- read.table(file='path_to_data', sep =";", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
```

And viewing the original missing data:

[image]

We can see there is no missing data in the original frame.

Now applying our function:

```
bank_nas <- add_random_nas_to_frame(bank, 5)
```

[image]