# add random missing values to a complete data frame (in R)

Tags: r

for testing purposes I need to add missing values to a data frame which has no missing values, how can I add 10% random `NA`s to my data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(20),v2=rnorm(20),v3=rnorm(20))
```

my idea was something like:

```
a <- sample(1:nrow(dat),3,replace=F)
b <- sample(1:ncol(dat),2,replace=F)

dat[a,b] <- NA
```

but this is not random enough. thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454265/r-randomly-insert-nas-into-dataframe-proportionaly), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873078/how-do-i-add-random-nas-into-a-data-frame) and [here](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/function-to-generate-a-random-data-set/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're asking for a way to create true random numbers, rather than how to implement it. If this is the case, you could use the `random` package available through CRAN which can sample random integers from [random.org](http://random.org)

```
install.packages("random")
require("random")
```

The details of the package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/random/index.html

I suggest you look especially at the vignette, '[random: an R package for true random numbers](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/random/vignettes/random-intro.pdf)' for how to obtain random integers.