# add exact proportion of random missing values to data.frame

Tags: r, random, na, missing-data

I would like to add random `NA` to a data.frame in R. So far I've looked into these questions:

[R: Randomly insert NAs into dataframe proportionaly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454265/3871924)

[How do I add random `NA`s into a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20873078/3871924)

[add random missing values to a complete data frame (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29650724/3871924)

Many solutions were provided here, but I couldn't find one that comply with these 5 conditions:

- Add really random NA, and not the same amount by row or by column
- Work with every class of variable that one can encounter in a data.frame (numeric, character, factor, logical, ts..), so the output must have the same format as the input data.frame or matrix.
- Guarantee an exact number or proportion *[note]* of NA in the output (many solutions result in a smaller number of NA since several are generated at the same place)
- Is computationnaly efficient for big datasets.
- Add the proportion/number of NA independently of already present NA in the input.

Anyone has an idea? 
I have already tried to write a function to do this (in an answer of the first link) but it doesn't comply with points N°3&4.
Thanks.

*[note] the exact proportion, rounded at +/- 1NA of course.*

Comment: Can you elaborate on how [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27454361/3627607) is not enough for you ? (And at least, checking the proportion of NA and redoing another pass with the missing percentage should do also)

Comment: @Tensibai yes thanks that's what I mean, i would like to output directly the right proportion/number of NA. If you can modify your suggestion to comply to this I would be glad

Comment: I can't, it's an existing answer, I don't see how to elaborate more on it. I don't get the need to have precisely a % (which in itself is roughly a nonsense). Getting the proprotion of NA is easy (`sum(is.na(df) / (nrow(df)*ncol(df)) )` and cheking if it's in an acceptable range, if not, do the NA adding again.

Comment: @Tensibai well, that's precisely why I ask a separate question that you are welcome to answer ;-)

Comment: Can't help but notice agenis put up an answer for the question you mentioned. Did your own answer to that not work on larger datasets? As it appears you had a way of proportionally adding NAs from that.

Comment: @Badger indeed, some months ago yes, but this code of mine doesn't guarantee the exact amount of NA, which I need now :-) (and is really not efficient for big datasets btw)

Comment: As Tensibai noted, when sampling for "True Random" guaranteeing a value would be counter intuitive and steps into Pseudo-randomness and you are forcing towards a specific outcome. Just but a checker as they mentioned and run and re-run until you are satisfied.

Comment: I'm sorry if you don't understand the reason of my question, I do a lot of model comparisons that also have to impute the data and this is really what I need. But I understand what you say, I could also design a simulation where the number of NA is also random, but this is not currently what I'm running. Maybe i'll study that another time :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way that I do it for my paper on `library(imputeMulti)` which is currently in review at JSS. This inserts `NA`'s into a random percentage of the whole dataset and scales well, It doesn't **guarantee** an exact number because of the case of `n * p * pctNA %% 1 != 0`.

```
createNAs <- function (x, pctNA = 0.1) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  p <- ncol(x)
  NAloc <- rep(FALSE, n * p)
  NAloc[sample.int(n * p, floor(n * p * pctNA))] <- TRUE
  x[matrix(NAloc, nrow = n, ncol = p)] <- NA
  return(x)
}
```

Obviously you should use a random seed for reproducibility, which can be specified before the function call.

This works as a general strategy for creating baseline datasets for comparison across imputation methods. I believe this is what you want, although your question (as noted in the comments) isn't clearly stated.

**Edit**: I do assume that `x` is complete. So, I'm not sure how it would handle existing missing data. You could certainly modify the code if you want, though that would probably increase the runtime by at least O(n*p)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I need.  I edited my question to be clearer and mention the rounding in the case of a proportion.

Comment: Hi @Alex W I allowed myself to add an answer expanding from your function, to treat the case with already present NA in the dataframe. You can take a look,

Answer (score 1):

Some users reported that Alex's answer did not address condition N°5 of my question. Indeed, when adding random `NA` on a dataframe that already contains missing values, the new ones will sometimes fall on the initial ones, and the final proportion will be somewhere between initial proportion and desired proportion... So I expand on Alex's function to comply with all 5 conditions:

I modify his `createNAs` function so that it enables one of 3 options:

- option *complement*: complement with NA up to the desired %
- option *add*       : add % of NA in addition to those already present
- option *none*      : add a % of NA regardless of those already present

For option 1 and 2, the function will work **recursively** until reached the desired proportion of `NA`:

```
createNAs <- function (x, pctNA = 0.0, option = "add"){
  prop.NA = function(x) sum(is.na(x))/prod(dim(x))
  initial.pctNA = prop.NA(x)

  if (  (option =="complement") & (initial.pctNA > pctNA)  ){
    message("The data already had more NA than the target percentage. Returning original data")
    return(x)
  }

  if (  (option == "none") || (initial.pctNA == 0)  ){
    n <- nrow(x)
    p <- ncol(x)
    NAloc <- rep(FALSE, n * p)
    NAloc[sample.int(n * p, floor(n * p * pctNA))] <- TRUE
    x[matrix(NAloc, nrow = n, ncol = p)] <- NA
    return(x)
  } else { # if another option than none:
    target = ifelse(option=="complement", pctNA, pctNA + initial.pctNA)
    while (prop.NA(x) < target) {
      prop.remaining.to.add = target - prop.NA(x)
      x = createNAs(x, prop.remaining.to.add, option = "none")
    }
    return(x)
  }
}
```