# Simulate attrition in R

Tags: r, na

I simulated the following general "survey experiment" data:

```
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
Q1 = sample(c(18:90), n, rep = TRUE), #age
Q2 = sample(c("m", "f"), n, rep = TRUE), #sex
Q3 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE, prob = c(0.55, 0.45)), #other general pre-treatment questions
Q4 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE),
Q5 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE), #treatment
Q6 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE), #post-treatment
Q7 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE),
Q8 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE),
Q9 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE),
Q10 = sample(c(0,1), n, rep = TRUE))
```

I'd like to simulate attrition (NA) data randomly. The following query deals with a similar issue: [How do I add random `NA`s into a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873078/how-do-i-add-random-nas-into-a-data-frame)

However, I'm interested in generating data that simulates respondents who left the survey completely, this may look something like this:

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10
18  m  1  0  NA NA NA NA NA NA
30  f NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
25  f  1  0  1  0  NA NA NA NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: E.g. `Q1[3:n] <- NA`. The question is, where you want to randomly set the first NA. You might want to use some distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Base R`,

```
invisible(
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) {
    a <- sample(3:10,1)
    df[x,a:ncol(df)] <<- NA
}
))

head(df)
```

gives,

```
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10
1 29  f  1  1  1  0 NA NA NA  NA
2 59  f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
3 48  m  1  0 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
4 38  m  0  1  0 NA NA NA NA  NA
5 30  f  1  1  0  0 NA NA NA  NA
6 57  m  1  1  1  1  0 NA NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really great. Is there any way to write the function such that some rows don't end with NAs?

Comment: Sure just change this line `sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) {`   with `sapply(sample(1:nrow(df),40),function(x) {` where 40 is the number of the `NA` rows you desire to have. You can play around with that number.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to assign attrition based on a specific value? for example if Q5==1? I tried ```a<-sample(Q5==1,1)``` or ```a<-sample("5"==1,1)``` but neither seems to work